# SQL Statement instance in java not closing

Tags: java, memory, heap-dump, try-with-resources

I can not find a place where the `Statement` does not close.

Any ideas?

```
new Thread(() -> { 
    while (true) { 
        try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement(); 
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `groups`")) { 
            while (rs.next()) { 
                executorService.submit(new VkBot(connection, rs)); 
            }
            Thread.sleep(1200); 
            rs.close(); 
        } catch (SQLException | InterruptedException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}).start();
```

VkBot.java:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

class VkBot implements Runnable {
    private Statement statement;
    private ResultSet rs;

    VkBot(Connection connection, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        this.statement = connection.createStatement();
        this.rs = rs;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ...
        } catch (NullPointerException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I get more than 600 `Statements` in 3 minutes.

[image]

Comment: in your thread in you are not closing the statement

Comment: also you are not closing anything if an exception is caught

Comment: This code makes no sense. What are you trying to accomplish by handing the `Connection` and `ResultSet` to a worker thread?

Comment: You create new `Statement` fro each `VkBot` object. And you create `VkBot` object for each row in `groups` table. So if table has a lot of  rows in a table you will have a lot of opened statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably getting an exception.
You have two AutoClosable objects in try, and you are closing the second and let the first open.
You should do one of the following:

- Let the second `ResultSet` open to the try-with-resource close it
- Close both

The first is the correct answer. If you are using try-with-resource, let the try close your resources.

Look if StatementImpl is an AutoClosable (or just Closable) implementation.

---

You are using the `try-with-resources` statement. All the resources allocated inside the `try` **SHOULD** be an `AutoClosable` implementation and the JVM will handle it, closing before leave the statement.

Read the java documentation for more information: [try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: If use try with resources, can i not close object?

Comment: Try with resources was done for you do not worry closing objects!